# How can I find Index of object in JArray based on a matching search?

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to find the index of an object inside an JArray based on a search.

What I want to end up is the ability to do this

```
JArray articles = (JArray)DetailedData["product"]["articlesList"][x]
```

The problem is I dont know how to find what x is

The JSON looks like this ( severly cut down )

```
 "articlesList": [
                {
                    "code": "0587026001",
```

I want to find the index x where code = 0587026001 but I cannot figure it out

I tried

```
var index = articlesList.IndexOf("$.[?(@.<code>=='0587026001')]");
```

but that returned -1

How can I find the index x where code matches as per above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope I understood your question correctly. You can find the Index as following

```
var result = JObject.Parse(json);
var selectedIndex = result["articlesList"].Select((x,index)=> new { Code= x.Value<string>("code"), Node = x, Index = index})
                                         .Single(x=>x.Code == "0587026003")
                                         .Index;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SelectTokens` to find the relevant tokens based on filter criteria.

The below code selects all the token under articleList which has code equals to '0587026001'

```
IEnumerable<JToken> tokens = o.SelectTokens("$..articlesList[?(@.Code == '0587026001')]");
```

Check this dotnet fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/EJvyfp which demonstrates the usage of it.

Sample code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        JArray o = JArray.Parse(@"[{
  'Stores': [
    'Lambton Quay',
    'Willis Street'
  ],
  'articlesList': [
    {
      'Code': '0587026001',
      'Name': 'Acme Co',
      'Products': [
        {
          'Name': 'Anvil',
          'Price': 50
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      'Code': '456',
      'Name': 'Contoso',
      'Products': [
        {
          'Name': 'Elbow Grease',
          'Price': 99.95
        },
        {
          'Name': 'Headlight Fluid',
          'Price': 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
'Stores': [
    'ABD',
    'XYZ'
  ],
  'articlesList': [
    {
    'Code': '789',
      'Name': 'Acme Co',
      'Products': [
        {
          'Name': 'Anvil',
          'Price': 50
        }
      ]
    },
    {
    'Code': '1234',
      'Name': 'Contoso',
      'Products': [
        {
          'Name': 'Elbow Grease',
          'Price': 99.95
        },
        {
          'Name': 'Headlight Fluid',
          'Price': 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]");

        //Console.WriteLine(o);

        IEnumerable<JToken> tokens = o.SelectTokens("$..articlesList[?(@.Code == '0587026001')]");
        Console.WriteLine(tokens.Count());
        Console.WriteLine(tokens.First());
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

The above program returns the output as

```
{
  "Code": "0587026001",
  "Name": "Acme Co",
  "Products": [
    {
      "Name": "Anvil",
      "Price": 50
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it:

```
private static int GetIndex(string code)
        {
            string json = "{\"product\": {\"articleList\": [{\"code\": \"0587026001\"}, {\"code\": \"0587026002\"}]}}";
            var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
            var articleList = JArray.Parse(jObject["product"]["articleList"].ToString());
            var requiredArticle = articleList.First(a => a["code"].ToString().Equals(code));
            return articleList.IndexOf(requiredArticle);
        }
```